# What to do in findXY method if no such object exists?

Tags: java

Assume I have a Java method

```
public X findX(...)
```

which tries to find an Object of type `X` fulfilling some conditions (given in the parameters). Often such functions cannot guarantee to find such an object. I can think of different ways to deal with this:

1. One could write an `public boolean existsX(...)` method with the same signature which should be called first. This avoids any kind of exceptions and null handling, but probably you get some duplicate logic.
2. One could just return null (and explain this in javadoc). The caller has to handle it.
3. One could throw a checked exception (which one would fit for this?).

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new Java 8 `Optional` class was made for this purpose.

If the object exists then you return `Optional.of(x)` where `x` is the object, if it doesn't then return `Optional.empty()`. You can check if an `Optional` has an object present by using the `isPresent()` method and you can get the object using `get()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `Optional` I would go with option 2.

In the case of 1. You'd be doing double work, first you have to check if X exists, but if it does, you're basically discarding the result, and you have to do the work again in `findX`. Although the result of `existsX` could be cached and checked first when calling `findX`, this would still be an extra step over just returning X.

In the case of 3. To me this comes down to usability. Sometimes you just *know* that `findX` will return a result (and if it doesn't, there is a mistake somewhere else), but with a checked exception, you would still have to write the `try` and (most likely empty) `catch` block.

So option 2 is the winner to me. It doesn't do extra work, and checking the result is optional. As long as you document the `null` return, there should be no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Guava (potentially other libraries, too) also offers an Optional class that might be worth exploring if your project  uses Guava since you seem to not use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you

- don't/can't/won't use Java 8 and its accompanying `Optional` type
- don't want another library dependency (like Guava) for a single class implementation

**but**

- you want something more robust than methods that can return `null` for which you have to have a check in all consumers (which was the standard before Java 8)

then writing your own `Optional` as an util class is the easiest option.